How can I replace usage of two @PlanningListVariable in Timefold?
Recently, I was tasked with writing a program in Java to solve an assignment problem. Essentially, I have a list of workers and tasks, and I need to organize them into teams. Each team should consist of 3 workers and a certain number of tasks. The number of tasks depends on the working time declared by the workers and the time required to complete each task. Initially, I started drafting the program with the idea of using two @PlanningListVariable fields. I thought this would be an easier way to approach the problem. I could separately assign workers and tasks, allowing me to add specific constraints (for example, one worker may prefer to work with another). In this way, the time constraint could also be calculated fairly easily. You would just take the list of tasks assigned to a particular group, calculate how long they would take, and then compare that to the shortest availability window in the given group of workers. I should also add that the order of tasks isn't important and can be omitted.
However, when I began implementing this, I discovered that Timefold currently doesn't support two @PlanningListVariable fields in the same planning entity. Does anyone know how to address this issue, or should I consider using another library? I would be grateful for any tips, as I've been looking for an answer for quite a long time.
So far, I have considered implementing Worker and Task as a single class that implements an interface, because tasks can also be interpreted as appointments. This way, I could refer to both of them as 'people.' This approach would reduce the number of @PlanningListVariable fields, but I think it might not be the best way to solve my problem. I also considered using multiple @PlanningVariable objects, but the number of tasks can vary between teams.
Edit 1:
Since then, my problem has evolved a bit, and the previous description is slightly outdated. Now, I am struggling with a single @PlanningListVariable. I came up with the idea that I could assign tasks statically and then add workers to them. However, the issue is that @PlanningListVariable does not allow duplicates, which is crucial because a single worker can be assigned to multiple tasks. Below is a simple implementation to better illustrate my problem:
Task.java:
public class Task {
private String taskName;

//Constructors, getters, setters, and equals
}

Worker.java:
public class Worker {
private String name;

//Constructors, getters, setters, and equals
}

WorkerTaskAssignment.java:
public class WorkersTaskAssignment {
@PlanningId
private UUID id;
@PlanningListVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "workersRange", allowsUnassignedValues = true)
List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
Task task;

//Constructors, getters, setters
}

WorkersTaskSolution.java:
public class WorkersTaskSolution {
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "workersRange")
private List<Worker> workers;
@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
private List<WorkersTaskAssignment> workersTaskAssignments;
@PlanningScore
private HardSoftScore score;

//Constructors, getters, setters
}

So I want to achieve something like this:
WorkerTaskAssignment1:
Worker1,
Worker2,
Worker3,
Task1
WorkerTaskAssignment2:
Worker1,
Worker2,
Worker3,
Task2
and so on. Now, I plan to duplicate workers so that there are as many of each worker as there are tasks. Unfortunately, this seems quite inefficient.

Can you provide a little code as an example? I'm not sure if it's crucial, but it would help us understand the question a bit better.

Sorry for the delay. I've updated my problem and added some simple code snippets to make it more precise. I still don't know if it would be better to post it as a new question, since it has changed quite a bit.
